# How to scroll to active text field in bottom sheet?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Here is self contained code that demo's the issue I am seeing.

When i click to view bottom sheet, it shows correctly:
[image]

But when I click into a textfield, it doesn't scroll the sheet up.
[image]

How do I get the screen to ensure field is visible and scrolls to the active text field? From what I can tell, it seems like it's related to using the DefaultTabController. On other screens, I don't have the issue...but still need to find a solution to this specific use-case.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TestScreenState createState() => _TestScreenState();
}

class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> {

  void showBottom() {
        showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        // isScrollControlled: true,
        builder: (_) {
          return Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
            child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text('testing bottom sheet.'),
                  TextFormField(),
                  TextFormField(),
                  TextFormField(),
                ],
              ),
          );
    
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('testing'),
             bottom: TabBar(
              indicatorColor: Colors.purple,
              tabs: [
                Tab(
                  child: Text(
                    'Zones',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                ),
                Text('My Profile', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black))
              ],
            ),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Container(
                child: Text('Tab 1'),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Text('This is tab 2'),
                    TextButton(onPressed: (){
                      showBottom();
                    },child: Text('Show bottom'),)
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment the line : isScrollControlled: true, this will allow the bottom sheet to take the space.